# ImageView Size Changes When Swiping Through Images

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-glide

I have a grid view that shows pictures from Flickr and when an image is selected, a new activity with the large version of the image is shown. The user can then swipe through the images. I'm loading the images with Glide and the problem I'm having is that once I swipe to a different sized image, such as a portrait image, the images get smaller.

```
package kyfb.android.kyfb.com.kyfb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by
 */
public class FlickrImageActivity extends BaseActivity {
    public static ImageButton backButton;
    public static ImageButton forwardButton;
    public static ImageView largeImage;


    String storageDirectory;

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    int position;

    static ArrayList<String> urls;

    static Context context;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);


        largeImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.large_image);


        storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        urls = FlickrActivity.picURLS;

        context = getApplicationContext();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            position = extras.getInt("position");
        }

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(urls.get(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(largeImage);



        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new OnSwipeGestureListener());
        largeImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        largeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class OnSwipeGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
            float deltaX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if ((Math.abs(deltaX) < SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) || (Math.abs(velocityX) < SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (deltaX < 0)
                {
                    handleSwipeRightToLeft();
                }
                else
                {
                    handleSwipeLeftToRight();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void handleSwipeLeftToRight()
    {
        System.out.println("Swipe Left to Right");

        if (position == 0) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(urls.get(urls.size() - 1))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(largeImage);


            position = urls.size() - 1;
        }
        else {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(urls.get(position - 1))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(largeImage);



            position--;
        }
    }

    private void handleSwipeRightToLeft()
    {
        System.out.println("Swipe Right to Left");

        if (position == urls.size() - 1) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(urls.get(0))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(largeImage);


            position = 0;
        }
        else {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(urls.get(position + 1))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(largeImage);


            position++;
        }

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
}
```

Landscape Image Selected:
[image]

Portrait Image Selected:
[image]

Portrait Image After Swiping from Landscape Image:
[image]

Comment: take all the images of same size

Comment: your images are not same size

Comment: How can I get that portrait image to stay its normal, larger size, when swiping from a different sized image?